# Filemaker Loop Through Portal

Tags: loops, portal, filemaker

I'm trying to create a loop to delete all portal rows. But the loop doesn't stop.
What am i doing wrong?

```
Go to Portal Row [Select; First]
Loop
  Delete Portal Row [No Dialog]
  Go To Portal Row [Next; Exit after last]
End Loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you have `Allow creation of related records through this relationship` on in your Relationships graph. This means that there will always be one record in the portal and that record can't be deleted because it is where a user would enter new data.

You could modify your script to something like this:

```
Go to Portal Row [Select; First]
Loop
   Delete Portal Row [No dialog]
   Go to Portal Row [Select; First]
   Exit Loop If [IsEmpty(relationship::index)]
End Loop
```

Where `relationship::index` is a value stored in every field of your foreign table.

Manipulating portals like this can be tricky. You might consider using a Go to Related Records script step go delete the records, instead. Something like:

```
Set Error Capture [On]
#
# Attempt to go to the related records, creating a new window "delete records"
Go to Related Record [Show only related records; From table: "<relatedtable>"; Using layout: "<relatedlayout>" (<relatedtable>); New window]
#
# If that failed exit the script. We should still be in the same window and layout.
If [not Get ( LastError )]
   Exit Script []
End If
#
# Otherwise delete all found records
Delete All Records [No dialog]
#
# And close the window we created
Close Window [Name: "delete steps"; Current file]
Set Error Capture [Off]
```

Comment: on the money! I did allow "Allow creation of related records through this relationship"  and i tried your script , but its deleting all the records...

Comment: It all makes sense now as to why the loop keeps going. I tried your script , but its deleting all the records... Let me explain: I set a portal to act like a list/ shopping cart. so that users can add records they would like to print to a portal which will be filed under a number. Adding the add to cart button adds the record / item to a portal. I tried to copy the way invoices work in FM. The script you mentioned does work , but it wont work for my purpose since its deleting all records in the cart tabel \ layout which the portal resided in .

Comment: your answer got my gears turning and here's what i did: I had a Portal count under the list which would show how many items are in the list/ cart , i added  an if statement to the loop to exit once the count is < 1 which worked perfectly.